# Why does asp.net tracing only work from time to time?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, trace

ASP.NET tracing seems very erratic. Sometimes it traces and sometimes it doesn't.

I trace from my ASCX using...

Trace.Write("etc. etc.");

My web.config looks as follows... (in WSS3)
I first ensure that SharePoint allows the page level tracing...

```
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true" DirectFileDependencies="10" TotalFileDependencies="50" AllowPageLevelTrace="true">
```

Here's my ASP.NET trace element...

```
<trace enabled="true" localOnly="false" pageOutput="true" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" />
```

And my System.Diagnostics trace...

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" >
    <listeners>
        <add name="listen" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\asptrace\log.txt" />
        <add name="listen2" type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"  />
    </listeners>
</trace>
```

Anything obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you checked the [request limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6915t83k.aspx) in your web.config? It's set to 10 by default, which means you'll only get trace output of the first 10 requests after the application starts.

```
<trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" />
```

Comment: You might also want to set mostRecent="true"

Comment: Excellent advice, thank you!

Increasing the RequestLimit solved the problem. Also, I tried using DebugView from sysinternals. Works well too.

Comment: Excellent answer, just what I've been looking for! (I used to have the same problem a few days ago) +1